# React Library For Adding and Following Tags?

Tags: reactjs, tags

Are there any libraries out there that allow you to add and follow tags. Similar to when you make a post on stackoverflow you can add at least one tag so more people will see your post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following links and use them as per your needs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input

https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput